# Connection issues on Crystal Reports for VB.Net application with a web hosted database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

My SQL Server database is hosted online and I am using Crystal Reports in my VB.Net application. How can I access the database procedures through Crystal Reports. I want to know about the connections.

My connection string is as follows:

```
Dim constr As String = "workstation id=jobschedule.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=modular_SQLLogin_1;pwd=*********;data source=jobschedule.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=jobschedule"
```

[image: What option should I select to proceed with the connections]

Comment: My Database is hosted on web.So am confused how to connect those procedures with the crystal reports.

Comment: Am i doing it the right way?

Comment: Try to use a UDL file in Crystal reports [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22995/Crystal-Report-database-connection-in-ASP-NET) ;).

Comment: Can you explain more about database, how other applications have been using the database. What kind of database etc.